# Using past and attention_mask at the same time for gpt2

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

I am processing a batch of sentences with different lengths, so I am planning to take advantage of the padding + attention_mask functionality in gpt2 for that.

At the same time, for each sentence I need to add a suffix phrase and run N different inferences. For instance, given the sentence "I like to drink coke", I may need to run two different inferences: "I like to drink coke. Coke is good" and "I like to drink coke. Drink is good". Thus, I am trying to improve the inference time for this by using the "past" functionality: https://huggingface.co/transformers/quickstart.html#using-the-past so I just process the original sentence (e.g. "I like to drink coke") once, and then I somehow expand the result to be able to be used with two other sentences: "Coke is good" and "Drink is good".

Below you will find a simple code that is trying to represent how I was trying to do this. For simplicity I'm just adding a single suffix phrase per sentence (...but I still hope my original idea is possible though):

```
from transformers.tokenization_gpt2 import GPT2Tokenizer
from transformers.modeling_gpt2 import GPT2LMHeadModel

tokenizer = GPT2Tokenizer.from_pretrained('gpt2', pad_token='<|endoftext|>')
model = GPT2LMHeadModel.from_pretrained('gpt2')

# Complete phrases are: "I like to drink soda without sugar" and "Go watch TV alone, I am not going"
docs = ["I like to drink soda", "Go watch TV"]
docs_tensors = tokenizer.batch_encode_plus(
    [d for d in docs], pad_to_max_length=True, return_tensors='pt')

docs_next = ["without sugar", "alone, I am not going"]
docs_next_tensors = tokenizer.batch_encode_plus(
    [d for d in docs_next], pad_to_max_length=True, return_tensors='pt')

# predicting the first part of each phrase
_, past = model(docs_tensors['input_ids'], attention_mask=docs_tensors['attention_mask'])

# predicting the rest of the phrase
logits, _ = model(docs_next_tensors['input_ids'], attention_mask=docs_next_tensors['attention_mask'], past=past)
logits = logits[:, -1]
_, top_indices_results = logits.topk(30)
```

The error I am getting is the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1434, in _exec
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "/Users/damiox/Workspace/xxLtd/yy/stress-test-withpast2.py", line 26, in <module>
    logits, _ = model(docs_next_tensors['input_ids'], attention_mask=docs_next_tensors['attention_mask'], past=past)
  File "/Users/damiox/.local/share/virtualenvs/yy-uMxmjV2h/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 532, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/damiox/.local/share/virtualenvs/yy-uMxmjV2h/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/modeling_gpt2.py", line 593, in forward
    inputs_embeds=inputs_embeds,
  File "/Users/damiox/.local/share/virtualenvs/yy-uMxmjV2h/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 532, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/damiox/.local/share/virtualenvs/yy-uMxmjV2h/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/modeling_gpt2.py", line 476, in forward
    hidden_states, layer_past=layer_past, attention_mask=attention_mask, head_mask=head_mask[i]
  File "/Users/damiox/.local/share/virtualenvs/yy-uMxmjV2h/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 532, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/damiox/.local/share/virtualenvs/yy-uMxmjV2h/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/modeling_gpt2.py", line 226, in forward
    self.ln_1(x), layer_past=layer_past, attention_mask=attention_mask, head_mask=head_mask
  File "/Users/damiox/.local/share/virtualenvs/yy-uMxmjV2h/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 532, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/damiox/.local/share/virtualenvs/yy-uMxmjV2h/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/modeling_gpt2.py", line 189, in forward
    attn_outputs = self._attn(query, key, value, attention_mask, head_mask)
  File "/Users/damiox/.local/share/virtualenvs/yy-uMxmjV2h/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/modeling_gpt2.py", line 150, in _attn
    w = w + attention_mask
RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (11) must match the size of tensor b (6) at non-singleton dimension 3

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Initially I thought this was related to https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/3031 - so I re-built latest master to try the fix, but I still experience the issue.

Comment: Maybe I wrongly assumed that I could get the same predictions by doing a inference over the full sentence vs doing the inference on the first part and using that first part (my "past" data) for a 2nd inference on the second part. I'm seeing different results... I'm not seeing the same topk words returned in both cases for a simple test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make your current code snippet work, you will have combine the previous and new attention mask as follows:

```
from transformers.tokenization_gpt2 import GPT2Tokenizer
from transformers.modeling_gpt2 import GPT2LMHeadModel
import torch

tokenizer = GPT2Tokenizer.from_pretrained('gpt2', pad_token='<|endoftext|>')
model = GPT2LMHeadModel.from_pretrained('gpt2')

# Complete phrases are: "I like to drink soda without sugar" and "Go watch TV alone, I am not going"
docs = ["I like to drink soda", "Go watch TV"]
docs_tensors = tokenizer.batch_encode_plus(
    [d for d in docs], pad_to_max_length=True, return_tensors='pt')

docs_next = ["without sugar", "alone, I am not going"]
docs_next_tensors = tokenizer.batch_encode_plus(
    [d for d in docs_next], pad_to_max_length=True, return_tensors='pt')

# predicting the first part of each phrase
_, past = model(docs_tensors['input_ids'], attention_mask=docs_tensors['attention_mask'])

# predicting the rest of the phrase
attn_mask = torch.cat([docs_tensors['attention_mask'], docs_next_tensors['attention_mask']], dim=-1)
logits, _ = model(docs_next_tensors['input_ids'], attention_mask=attn_mask, past=past)
logits = logits[:, -1]
_, top_indices_results = logits.topk(30)
```

For the case that you want to test two possible suffixes for a sentence start you probably will have to clone your past variable as many times as you have suffixes. That means that the batch size of your prefix input_ids has to match the batch size of your suffix input_ids in order to make it work.

Also you have to change the positional encodings input of your suffix input_ids (GPT2 uses absolute positional encodings) if one of your prefix input_ids is padded (this is not shown in the code above - please take a look at https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/3021 to see how it's done).

Comment: Thanks @patrick-von-platen - It's not failing with latest master. Currently, I was not using past so I'm doing redundant work looks like... I'm planning to use this N_prefix+N_suffix algorithm with the past functionality to improve inference time for my use case, but I'm worried if my predictions may change because of this? I'm trying prefix+suffix(with past) vs fulldoc for a single doc without any padding for simplicity with this comparison, and I get different predictions... Is that expected?

Comment: Also my prefixes (my past) have in average 44 tokens. and my suffixes have in average 5 tokens. If I were using this prefix+suffix(with past) algorithm I would just compute the 44 tokens first , clone them, and then run predictions for the suffixes with 5 tokens in average. I think my inference time should be much better by doing this instead of running N inferences with the full 44+5 tokens. What do you think in terms of inference time. Should my approach be much better?

Comment: See https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/3095 for answer